# Store redirects in Scrapy Items

Tags: python, redirect, scrapy

I would like to include a response field in my scrapy `items.py` file as follows:

```
class ScrapyItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    h1 = Field()
    response = Field()
```

I thought I could just use `response.status` in my `spider.py` file, but that gives me a `200` status code every time. I would like it to fill in with a `301`, `302`, or `404` if the page is redirected or not found.

Is there any way to do this in Scrapy?

Comment: There won't be any item if the page wasn't loaded. Do you need just a list of urls with the response codes?

Comment: I need the response codes as well as html elements on the page. I am loading and parsing the pages in a parse_item method and am getting a response code by just calling response.status. This returns 200 codes every time, no redirects or 404s

Comment: The html for 404 is most likely "Page not found" page with no items to parse. 302 and 301 responses most of the time don't have any html at all. The point is, there're nothing to parse on those pages.

If you are trying to build something like a simple website map (links-response codes), scrapy isn't the best or easiest tool for that.

Comment: I was afraid of that, do you know of any good tools for that?

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy swallows there kind of things for you (that's a design decission). You need to do two things:

1. In your spider, write the following to [handle error responses](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.httperror)

   `handle_httpstatus_list = range( 400, 427 ) + range( 500, 511 )`
2. Disable the [RedirectMiddleware](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/redirect.py) that handles the 3xx status headers

Now you can read the status from the `response.status` field.